# Cyclic dependency found. sequelize-typescript inside nest.js

Tags: sequelize.js, nestjs, sequelize-typescript

I'm getting this error:

> Error: Cyclic dependency found. users is dependent of itself.
> Dependency chain: users -> orders => users

I'm trying to move my project from express+sequelize to nest+sequelize-typescript stack. As i remember right, i solved the same error on previous stack with circular dependencies by moving association code from model files to one file.
I searched the internet and documentations, seems like my code looks right but it doesn't work.

Official sequelize docs suggest me to add

```
constraints: false
```

to my association's code, but sequelize-typescript doesn't have an instrument to do it.

What i'm doing wrong? Please help me!

Entry point:

```
import { Module } from '@nestjs/common';
import { AppController } from './app.controller';
import { AppService } from './app.service';
import { SequelizeModule } from '@nestjs/sequelize';
import { ConfigModule } from '@nestjs/config';
import { Dialect } from 'sequelize';
import { UsersModule } from '../base-modules/users/users.module';
import { OrdersModule } from '../base-modules/orders/orders.module';

@Module({
  imports: [
    ConfigModule.forRoot({
      envFilePath: process.env.NODE_ENV !== 'prod' ? '.env.development' : '.env',
    }),
    SequelizeModule.forRoot({
      dialect: process.env.DB_DIALECT as Dialect,
      host: process.env.DB_HOST,
      port: +process.env.DB_PORT,
      username: process.env.DB_USER,
      password: process.env.DB_PASS,
      database: process.env.DB_NAME,
      synchronize: true,
      autoLoadModels: true,
    }),
    UsersModule,
    OrdersModule,
  ],
  controllers: [AppController],
  providers: [AppService],
})
export class AppModule {}
```

Users

```
import {
  AllowNull,
  AutoIncrement,
  Column,
  DataType,
  Default,
  HasMany,
  HasOne,
  Model,
  PrimaryKey,
  Table,
  Unique,
} from 'sequelize-typescript';
import { IUserAttributes, IUserCreationAttributes, UserRole } from './user.types';
import { Order } from '../orders/order.model';

@Table({
  timestamps: true,
  tableName: 'users',
})
export class User
  extends Model<IUserAttributes, IUserCreationAttributes>
  implements IUserAttributes
{
  @AutoIncrement
  @PrimaryKey
  @Column(DataType.INTEGER.UNSIGNED)
  id!: number;

  @AllowNull(false)
  @Unique
  @Column(DataType.STRING(64))
  name!: string;
  
  @HasMany(() => Order)
  orders?: Order[];
}
```

Orders

```
import {
  AllowNull,
  AutoIncrement,
  BelongsTo,
  Column,
  DataType,
  Default,
  ForeignKey,
  HasMany,
  HasOne,
  Model,
  PrimaryKey,
  Table,
} from 'sequelize-typescript';
import {
  IOrderAttributes,
  IOrderCreationAttributes,
  OrderCustom,
  OrderStatus,
  OrderType,
  TimeStamp,
} from './order.types';
import { User } from '../users/user.model';

@Table({
  timestamps: true,
  tableName: 'orders',
})
export class Order
  extends Model<IOrderAttributes, IOrderCreationAttributes>
  implements IOrderAttributes
{
  @AutoIncrement
  @PrimaryKey
  @Column(DataType.INTEGER.UNSIGNED)
  id!: number;

  @ForeignKey(() => User)
  @Column
  userId!: number;

  @BelongsTo(() => User, 'userId')
  user?: User;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem was simple: in one of the tables, I accidentally used a name that had already been used:

```
@Table({
  timestamps: true,
  tableName: 'orders',
})
class Orders {}

@Table({
  timestamps: true,
  tableName: 'orders',
})
class Reviews {}
```

After fixing it, the error disappeared.